# Installing jmf.bin file in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, java

I am new to Ubuntu and want to install `.bin` file on my pc which generates jar files after completion of installation.

It is a jmf (.bin) file which supports Java Media Framework for running the videos in Java.

Following commands I used:

```
chomd a+x filename
sudo ./filename
```

Installation starts in the terminal but After some time It gives:

```
-> No such file
-> ) unexpected
-> No such directory.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, your file is in your <kbd>Downloads</kbd> folder, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/jmf.bin
```

and start the installation with:

```
sudo ~/Downloads/jmf.bin
```

---

If your file is in your current folder

```
chmod +x jmf.bin
```

and start with

```
sudo ./jmf.bin
```

---

If your file contains brackets, eg. `(` and/or `)` than use double quotes for the filename

```
chmod +x "jmf(.bin)"
```

and start with

```
sudo "./jmf(.bin)"
```